# Multiple RewriteCond, not working

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2

I have Multiple RewriteCond in sequence which i expect to work as IF/ELSE pattren. 
i.e in plain text, it looks like this

```
IF there is no Cookie THEN redirect to other host, 
ELSE, Serve the requested file
```

I have RewriteCond as below:

```
RewriteEngine on         
#If there is no cookie in the request fwd the request to ABC
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^.*Cookie.*$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://abc.xyz.com:<port>$1 [P,L]
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://abc.xyz.com/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://abc.xyz.com:<port>/
#else serve the file    
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie} ^xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-credentials-a=.*$ [NC]
    RewriteRule /([^/]*\.nff).*$ /srv/samba/Assets/$1 [NC,L]
```

But, the Else RewriteCond is not working, even the request header has Cookie, it still getting redirected. 
Is there anything i am missing ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok..I found solution after reading apache docs. Below is the modified code

```
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie} ^xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-credentials-a=.*$ [NC]
    RewriteRule /([^/]*\.nff).*$ /srv/samba/Assets/$1 [NC,L]    

#If there is no cookie in request fwd the request to    abc                  
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://abc.xyz.com:<port>$1 [P]
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://abc.xyz.com/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://abc.xya.com:<port>/
```

As there is just IF then Else, then no need to use 'Skip' all I need to do is stop looping. So I added [L] in the first rule and removed other rewritecond.